# iPhone GPS Coordinate uploading

Tags: iphone, gps

I am looking for a way for the iPhone to push out GPS coordinates every hour and display them on a public website.

I have a friend biking across the country for charity and he wants everyone to be able to view his progress.  Any creative ideas besides the iPhone?  Any ideas with minimal programming would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help!
Dylan

Answer (score 0):

What about using gpsnerd.com? Signup for an account. Can track live position. Mark your account as public to share with others.

I created thi site. Let me know if you have questions.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I'd probably just use [Runkeeper Live](http://blog.runkeeper.com/uncategorized/introducing-runkeeper-live)